# How to use VisualStateManager with content Dialogue control in uwp

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp-xaml

Is there any way to use visualStateManager with content Dialogue control in uwp application.

Comment: Do you mean `ContentDialog` control ?

Comment: yes. I am having trouble to make it responsive. please Help..

Comment: Please share your xaml and what feature that your want realize

Comment: I got the solution..We can't apply visual state triggers or wrap panel to contentDialog and if we use it , it won't work. The solution is to make the POPUP using the usercontrol control , apply all the triggers or wrap panel that you want and then out that usercontrol inside your contentdialog. This is the only way to make it responsive.

Comment: If you found the solution, you could post answer below and mark yourself.

Comment: posted my solution pls check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Put all your popUp controls in the control as follow:

```
`<Grid Background="White">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1000" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>

                </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="750" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="BlueRect.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter Target="RedRect.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="BlueRect.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Target="RedRect.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <StackPanel>
            <Rectangle x:Name="BlueRect" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Blue" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="RedRect" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" />
            <Button Content="Change Style" Width="500" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>`
```

## Transfer event of user controls to contentdialog if there is any:

```
`public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public delegate void MyEventHandler(object source, EventArgs e);

        public static event MyEventHandler OnNavigateParentReady;

        public MyUserControl1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnNavigateParentReady(sender,null);
        }
    }`
```

## Create contentDialog control and use the created user control there as follow:

```
` <Grid >
        <local:MyUserControl1 />
    </Grid>`
```

## Now Handle the transferred events of your user control on contentDialog code behind as follow:

```
`public sealed partial class ContentDialog1 : ContentDialog
    {
        public ContentDialog1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MyUserControl1.OnNavigateParentReady += test;
        }

        private void test(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button bt = (Button)source;
            if (bt.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }`
```

## Now simply make a call to your popUp(contentDialog) from where you want to.I made a call on the button click event as shown:

```
` ContentDialog1 popup = new ContentDialog1() { };
        public uc_test()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();                       
        }

        private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await popup.ShowAsync();
        }`
```

Works fine for me and helped me to create a responsive popUp as it applies all the triggers that you applied on your user control when the main window shrink.

Thanks.